# Virtual Wayland Display Server Possible?

Tags: wayland, testing

Are there any equivalents to X11's Xvfb for Wayland?

So wayland applications can run with OpenGL etc without having to connect to a physical graphics card?

---

Asking since I would like to run tests for graphical applications that can run on a headless server for example.

Note: while it's technically possible to run wayland within a virtual X11 session, I'd rather not depend on this for my testing framework if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any compositor may provide a headless interface, the reference implementation `weston` for example, has a headless back-end.

It can be invoked as follows:

```
weston --no-config --socket=wl-test-env --backend=headless
```

Applications can then be launched in it with the environment variable set to `WAYLAND_DISPLAY=wl-test-env`, for example:

```
env WAYLAND_DISPLAY=wl-test-env wayland-info
```

---

It's worth noting this can run from a terminal or X11, as it doesn't depend on an existing graphical session. Using unique sockets you may also run multiple weston compositors in parallel.

*This has been used for automated graphical tests in Blender 3D.*

Answer (score 5):

[Sway](https://swaywm.org/) supports this: its [`WLR_BACKENDS`](https://github.com/swaywm/wlroots/blob/master/docs/env_vars.md) variable can be set to `headless`, and it will run without any display.

See [swayvnc](https://github.com/bbusse/swayvnc) for an example of this being used in practice; this is the base for [swayvnc-firefox](https://github.com/bbusse/swayvnc-firefox) which provides a VNC-accessible “headless” Firefox.