# On-Demand Virtual Display as a kmod

Tags: wayland, headless, sway, rdp, mutter

I have a usecase where I want to use RDP on an Debian based machine to control it remotely.

I want to be able to fully use the onboard GPU to run tasks based on CUDA or anything else. My usecase does not revolve around the following, but miners use dummy HDMI plugs to mock this functionality. However, the resolution & refresh rate is fixed; this seems like a poor solution to a semi-complex issue.

As far as I know, gnome-shell currently doesn't support headless RDP. Headless/no monitor connected RDP on Windows works as intended from what I've seen, however I do not have the luxury (or rather, the misfortune) of having this solution at my disposal. I, unfortunately, cannot switch desktop environments to anything else other than GNOME. This is noteworthy, because [this is an answer to a similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/762077).

What I'm getting at, is that there should be a low-level (and hence, a cross-DE/compositor) way to emulate a display for either onboard and/or connected GPUs. It's a somewhat complex task to grasp though, because compositors use Direct Rendering Manager, who in turn (as I understood) speaks to the appropriate kmod(s) to handle the detection of monitors.

If anyone could shed a light into how the stack actually works regarding detection & rendering with DRM, that'd be a great starter!
How would I begin with implementing such a kmod? Would I have to interface & mock a connected display for a device that's connected to a GPU?

Thank you in advance.